# How to avoid warning when i use wrong password and email in login form of imap authorization?

Tags: php, imap

How to avoid this warning and notices when i use wrong password and email in my login form in imap_open:

> Warning: 'imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX' and
>
> Notice: Unknown: IMAP protocol error: Client aborted AUTHENTICATE command. i145-v6mb122753825lfi (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Notice: Unknown: IMAP Authentication cancelled (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

I need some check when i use wrong password and email, close imap connection and echo smth like this 'wrong password or email!'. I tried to evoid this, but it is not working. Please tell me, what i am doing wrong.

function imap_open:

```
function open_mailbox($auth_user, $auth_password) {
    $mailbox = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
    if($imap = imap_open($mailbox, $auth_user, $auth_password)){
        imap_open($mailbox, $auth_user, $auth_password);
        echo "success";
    } else {
        imap_close($imap);
        echo 'fail';
    }
}
```

function of login form

```
function display_login_form($action) { ?>
<form method="post" action="index.php?action=log-in">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>LOGIN</p>
            </div>
            </br>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>MAIL</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="username" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </br>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <p>PASSWORD</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </br>
                <div>
                    <input type='submit' value='LOGIN'>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

index.php

```
$username = "";
$password = "";
if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
}
if(null!==($username && $password)) {
    if(open_mailbox($username, $password)) {
        $action = 'view-mailbox';
        $_SESSION['auth_user'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['auth_password'] = $password;
    } else {
        $status .= "<p>Wrong password or email</p>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Barthy Yes, TNX a lot))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `imap_errors()` to get rid of warnings and notices:

> When imap_errors() is called, the error stack is subsequently cleared.
>
> **[Source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-errors.php)**

Simply call it before calling `imap_close()`.

---

Also note, that you call `imap_open()` twice in this block, once in the assignment inside the if condition, and once right after it:

```
if($imap = imap_open($mailbox, $auth_user, $auth_password)){
    imap_open($mailbox, $auth_user, $auth_password);
    echo "success";
}
```

This is not necessary. If the `$imap = imap_open($mailbox, $auth_user, $auth_password)` assignment does not return `FALSE`, you do not need to open the imap once more.